# Importing print.js using webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, printjs

I am trying to import the [print.js](https://github.com/crabbly/Print.js) library into the vendor bundle in my project using webpack. For some reason it cannot resolve the module. The print.js node_modules folder contains some interesting files - `webpack.mix.js` and the `src/index.js` appears to be written in ES6. Maybe I am missing a dependency or ES6 support?

my `webpack.config.js`:

```
var webpack = require("webpack"),
    path = require("path");

const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

module.exports = {

 context: __dirname + "/public",
  entry: {
    app: "./application.js",
    vendor: ["angular", "angular-route", "scrollreveal", "clipboard", "print.js"]  
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/public/scripts",
    filename: "trails.bundle.js"
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({name: "vendor", filename: "vendor.bundle.js"}),
    new Dotenv({
      path: './.env', // Path to .env file (this is the default)
    })
  ]
};
```

The error:

```
ERROR in multi angular angular-route scrollreveal clipboard print.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'print.js'
```

Answer (score 1):

The library was renamed to `print-js` in npm.

Try:

```
...
entry: {
  app: "./application.js",
  vendor: ["angular", "angular-route", "scrollreveal", "clipboard", "print-js"]  
},
...
```